# Documentation for brownie env variables

Tags: brownie, pyethereum, documentation

I'm using brownie for a while to interact with ethereum, and I've always used `ETHERSCAN_TOKEN` to publish the source code in Etherscan, however I'm unable to find this env variable in the documentation... and so I might be missing possibly some great feature of brownie just because there is no page that reports all of those magic env variables

Can someone please please answer with some documentation where we can find this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're right! It's currently missing from the docs. Could you make this an issue on the [brownie repo](https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie).

Comment: Thank you again, I've already opened the issue yesterday https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/1258